# Typescript - Why `methods` property doesn't exist in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, typescript, definition

I was coding typescript in nodejs. When I was coding mongoose schema, Typescript compiler telled me as following:

```
app/models/user.schema.ts(15,12): error TS2339: Property 'methods' does not exis
t on type 'Schema'.
```

I felt odd. I had refer doc in `Instance methods` section of [guide](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html). It mentions as following:

```
// assign a function to the "methods" object of our animalSchema
animalSchema.methods.findSimilarTypes = function (cb) {
  return this.model('Animal').find({ type: this.type }, cb);
}
```

I think `methods` is a available property or API. But for typescript, it's wrong.

Next, I lookup definition. I find [method(name: string, fn: Function)](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/mongoose/mongoose.d.ts#L149) and [method(method: Object)](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/mongoose/mongoose.d.ts#L150) these properties but it hasn't `methods`.

---

In short, you don't answer me why author of mongoose definition doesn't define the property. I need a answer the `methods` in `mongoose` is actually available or not?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no such property as "methods" in pure javascript. Its is a mongoose specifics. Please note that node.js use internally the same google V8 javascript engine as the chrome browser does - so there is no such thing as pure javascript for node.js.

Answer (score 0):

`methods` property does exist in mongoose, but using mongoose methods/statics the way like javascript in typescript will cause error. Here are some workarounds.

workaround A:

```
userSchema['methods'].findSimilarTypes = function (cb) {
  return this.model('Animal').find({ type: this.type }, cb);
}
```

workaround B :

```
userSchema.method('findSimilarTypes', function (cb) {
  return this.model('Animal').find({ type: this.type }, cb);
})
```

Comment: This just doesn't work. Also, there is no explanation given as to why this answer was posted.

Answer (score 0):

Today mongoose has released new version of mongoose 5.11.0 . If you have "mongoose": "^5.x.xx" in package.json you will get many errors like this. So, I suggest to change "mongoose": "~5.x.xx" to fix them all.